# How to implement data from one web browser to another

Tags: python, selenium

i'm using Selenium WebDriver with Python 2.7.14 on Firefox browser. i'm tring to get text from .JSON file that located at this url: http://a360ci.s3.amazonaws.com/Jmx/einat_world_bank.json and implement all the data in the main area on this url: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/
This is my code:

```
driver = self.driver      
driver.get('http://a360ci.s3.amazonaws.com/Jmx/einat_world_bank.json')
RawData = driver.find_element_by_id("tab-1")
RawData.click()
self.driver.implicitly_wait(2)
content = driver.find_element_by_class_name("data").text
driver.get('http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/')
MainField = driver.find_element_by_id("edit")
MainField.send_keys(content)
```

*I moved to RawData tab because on Firefox the JSON not parsing well
*After the second url opened the program stuck and nothing happens. what can be the problem and how it can be solved? Thanks.

Comment: send_keys will emulate keystorke on each character at a time, so if json has large data it will take up time. what you need is copy and paste and not send_keys

Answer (score 0):

Not clear the root cause. suggest you to fetch the json by http client library, not by opening in browser and get from browser.  Otherwise your code can't run cross browser. Different browser will display the json content with different DOM tree.  I think there is no 'tab-1' when open in Chrome.  Another reason is firefox report parsing fail, but chrome has no such issue.

Because the json content is too long. suggest you not use send_keys(), you can try 
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', textbox, jsonstring)